# Coverity on Travis CI not working because 'scan.coverity.com' isn't trusted

Tags: travis-ci, coverity

I'm trying to add Coverity to my Travis CI builds, but for some reason, even after following the [instructions to enable Coverity](https://scan.coverity.com/projects/dguest-lwtnn/builds/new?tab=travis_ci), producing [this `.travis.yml` file](https://github.com/dguest/lwtnn/blob/master/.travis.yml#L8), the Coverity status seems to be stuck in "pending". Looking at the [logs from Travis](https://travis-ci.org/dguest/lwtnn/builds/140559395) it appears to have an several errors:

```
Downloading Coverity Scan Analysis Tool...
ERROR: The certificate of ‘scan.coverity.com’ is not trusted.
ERROR: The certificate of ‘scan.coverity.com’ hasn't got a known issuer.
```

I'm not sure if this is *why* the service is stuck in "pending", but it looks suspicious. Is there some way to fix this? Am I missing a bigger problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug, the workaround, and the resolution by the Travis CI team is documented in [this issue on github](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/6142) (closed less than 24 hours ago at the time of writing).